# Has anyone worked with TestCocoon?

Tags: testing, code-coverage, testcocoon

I was trying out TestCocoon the other day, and everything seemed great. I compiled my code using `cscl`,`cslib` and `cslink` and I was expecting this to take care of all the instrumentation. I get some .csmes files and .exe.csmes files, but when I load them into the CoverageBrowser I cannot see anything relevant. No covered/uncovered lines. All the lines are grey.

Is anything else needed in order for TestCocoon to report coverage? Do I need to modify my source files? I also posted on their forums here, but no result:

http://www.testcocoon.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=44

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Dont use testcocoon, I am currently using it, and its shoddy as hell. Pay for something better (it will cost alot). It is the ultimate death sentence, seriously, don't do it. Whatever you do, stay away from testcocoon at all costs. Worst move ever. You might as well sell your kids for drug money.

Comment: Interesting, I was tempted to have a go with TestCocoon but I might try to convince the boss to buy PC-Lint instead.

Comment: it would be really great if you could manage to communicate anything about what issues you actually encountered, rather than just bashing it?

Answer (score 5):

I tried this tool with few projects using Visual Studio 2008, and I found:

**Pros:**
- it can collect results from multiple runs, you can run your software at different machines and collect results together
- it has useful GUI for browsing results
- you can merge coverage from many modules and anlyse it as whole application
- forum works, I submited two problems and got implemented fixtures in few days
- it works almost without any problems (I found two minor compilation problems) with quite complicated sources, with tons of templates, boost::spirit parsers, other boost stuff (including meta-programming modules etc.), STL, Qt (everything together)
- well documented
- it's free

**Cons:**
- instrumentation is definitely slow
- multi-process single project compilation using Visual Studio 2008 doesn't work, only one file at a time is compiled which makes building slower (you will get better performance building whole solution with many projects)

At this moment I didn't try to use this tool for continuous coverage measurement.

Either way, in my opinion it's worth to try.

BTW, Tony, PC-Lint is static-analysis tool, isn't it? interesting idea to compare it with dynamic-analysis tool...

Answer (score 1):

TestCocoon (now at 1.6.7) works well with the small C code bases we tend to unit test. The performance impact seems about normal for other instrumentation methods we've used.

We are able to extract coverage information in our makefiles and the coverage browser is very useful.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question!?